# How to manipulate a value on a sqlite database on an android app using SQLiteDatabase.Update() method

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

I need to do something similar to what this query do. Manipulated value depends on its previous value.

```
UPDATE Repetitions SET reps = reps + 1 where id = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `execSQL()` to run raw SQL like this directly.

Comment: thanks mate, I thought there is a way to use the built in functions!